# StreetsView: how to configure side links

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

StreetsView interiors has the possibility to show of different views of given building (rooms, places etc.) switchable using links on the right named O, S1, S2, N0 etc. I want to present this StreetvView element on different pages, but I want to set different initial views on those pages (on page #1 is visible view corresponding to link 0, on page #2 is visible view corresponding to link S1 etc). I can't find any options in StreetvView API to do this.

[image: StreetsView Example]

```
function initialize() {
    var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(12.345, 12.345);
    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: bryantPark,
        pov: {
            heading: 20,
            pitch: 0
        },
        zoom: 1
    };
    var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('street-view-canvas'),
        panoramaOptions
    );
    myPano.setVisible(true);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You're not showing your code for creating the O, S1, S2, N0 etc. buttons. But in that code you would want to set up callbacks that would change the panorama position and pov.